# Cordova facebook plugin invalid key hash

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm build APP, sign APK with keystore. Get keystore hash with command 
`keytool -exportcert -alias electo -keystore my-key.jks  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` add this hash to my app in fb.com. Install local app. FB auth works good.

Uploaded apk in play market. Download it and it doesn't work. Invalid hash key Facebook. A try to add this key that displayed in error to my app, but it's said "Invalid key hash" too.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing could be happened, if you have enrolled to Google Play App Signing. They are generating a new signing key for us. Since Facebook recognize your app previous key hash as invalid key hash. You have to get the key (SHA1) that was generated by Play Store(like in below image) and convert it to `base64` and use that key. You could use this [link](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en) to convert your `SHA1` key to `base64`.

[image]

Hope this will help to you!